# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tableToJSON is not a function

Tags: json, html-table

Has something changed with this great jquery plugin? I keep getting this "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tableToJSON is not a function" -error although I have resources correct.

Comment: Well, I got the error when I tried with wordpress site, but not with plain html file.

Comment: want to know if this code is live

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example.

```
<script>
$('#convert-table').click( function() {
  var table = $('#example-table').tableToJSON(); // Convert the table into a javascript object
  console.log(table);
  alert(JSON.stringify(table));
});
</script>
```

refer this link

http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/

Comment: do not forget to add the necessary jQuery like  jquery.js and tabletojson.js etc.